# What would they call the US President's personal plane?

Tags: usa, call-sign, head-of-state-transport

Air Force One is called that because it is operated by the Air Force.  The President's personal helicopter is called Marine One because it is operated by the Marines.

What would the President's personal aircraft be called?

Comment: Easily found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_One).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd expect [Executive One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_One):

> Executive One is the call sign designated for any United States civil aircraft when the President of the United States is on board.

Comment: I actually heard it was `Corporate One`.

Comment: @wbeard52 never heard that one. Most likely it's some company's way to refer to their own aircraft when used by the president of the corporation, not the president of the country.

Comment: I don't remember where.  I think it was from a friend I was talking to.

Comment: @wbeard52 I thought you were making a political joke, which was a much better explanation. ;-)

Comment: Almost an example: Nelson Rockefeller continued to use his personal Gulfstream while Ford's Vice President and it was known as Executive Two.

Answer (score 14):

Executive One is used while the President is on a civil aircraft according to [FAA JO 7110.65W](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf) (.pdf). Apparently, this information hasn't been published in the AIM for a while.

> (b)
>   When  the  President  is  aboard  a  civil
>   aircraft, state the words “Executive One.”

(Page 2-4-10)